# Incorrect Meta reputation in site switcher

Tags: bug, reputation, stack-exchange-button

I opened the site switcher and found that my Meta Stack Overflow reputation was not right:

[image: the bug]

On both Main and Meta Stack Overflow, the reputation counter on my profile page show that the real amount is the same:

[image: Meta and Main have the same amount]

Why does the site switcher have such a different amount? I have seen this problem for a few weeks now and it's starting to annoy me.